# Naming rules for HTML5 custom data attribute(data-)

Tags: html, attributes

I tried to use `data-userId`, but firebug shows it as `data-userid` (with a lowercase "i").
It seems that we should not use uppercase letters in custom data attributes.
What is the naming rules for HTML5 custom data attributes?
Please let me know any best practices to use it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Straight from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

> #### *3.2.3.9 Embedding custom non-visible data with the [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-data-*) attributes*
>
> A **custom data attribute** is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string "`data-`", has at least one character after the hyphen, is [XML-compatible](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#xml-compatible), and **contains no [uppercase ASCII letters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#uppercase-ascii-letters).**

(emphasis added)

---

What does XML-compatible mean?

> Attribute names are said to be **XML-compatible** if they match the [`Name`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name) production defined in XML and they contain no U+003A COLON characters (:).

What is the `Name` production rule?

> [4]    `NameStartChar`    ::=      `":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6]  | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]`
>   [4a]      `NameChar`     ::=      [`NameStartChar`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar) `| "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]`
>   [5]      `Name`     ::=      [`NameStartChar`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar) `(`[`NameChar`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameChar)`)*`

Comment: XML-compatible means?

Comment: Why? I don't think I agree.

Comment: There, we wont get answer to a particular question. Anyway, StackOverflow is designed to give good answer to a particular question. It will be good to users to point out the full details in this answer than forcing them to read specs. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know which rule is that, I haven't found it in specs from above post but if you want to get camelCase data item using jquery data('userId') you have to add attribute data-user-id='xx'

Answer (score 3):

The data attribute name must be at least one character long and must be prefixed with 'data-'. It should not contain any uppercase letters.

The name of a data attribute must begin with the string ‘data-’ and must contain at least one character after the hyphen using any HTML naming convention.

[Reference HTML5 Data](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.

Complete guidelines can be found in the [W3 Recommendation.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)