# ASP.NET C# Adding attribute to control - it comes out in lowercase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a ListBox control:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstBox" />
```

In code behind, I use the following:

```
int _maxListBoxSelection = 3;
lstBox.Attributes.Add("data-maximumSelectionSize", _maxListBoxSelection.ToString());
```

However, when I inspect the HTML the `ListBox` is rendered so:

```
<select id="blah_lstBox" name="blah$lstBox" data-maximumselectionsize="3" />
```

It seems similar to the reported thing here: [How to prevent asp.net to make lowercase my custom attribute I placed in a server control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066537/how-to-prevent-asp-net-to-make-lowercase-my-custom-attribute-i-placed-in-a-serve)

This is in .NET 4.0, using Visual Studio 2010.

Obviously, it means for accessing these via JavaScript it's nice to know that everything will be converted to lowercase.

So, why does ASP.NET change these to lower case? Can this behaviour be changed?

**EDIT to ADD**

Just tried with non `data` attributes and again ASP.NET changes these to lowercase. So if I add `aCustomAttribute` it gets changed to `acustomattribute` - is this expected?

Comment: Did you check that other question and the one that is being referred to there?

Comment: You should be using data-maximum-selection-size anyways for the attribute instead camel case.

Comment: Yes, and that's a setting on the Visual Studio - as per the linked question, doesn't refer to rendered output.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen should I? Can you link to a reference for this being the case please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533402/naming-rules-for-html5-custome-data-attributedata, of course you can use the naming of maximumselectionsize, but it makes it harder to interpret than maximum-selection-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "by design" behavior. From [XHTML Standards in Visual Studio and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/exc57y7e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), MSDN, section "ASP.NET Features for XHTML Conformance":

> Tag and attribute names are rendered in lowercase

So this is done to conform with XHTML standard. As others have noted, one should use dashes instead of came case to ensure readability of the attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

[The HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) restricts the usage to lower case

> All attributes on HTML elements in HTML documents get ASCII-lowercased
>   automatically

Comment: [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) says _All attribute names on HTML elements in HTML documents get ASCII-lowercased automatically_