# Click anchor will change background color of DIV on other page

Tags: jquery

I have 10 anchors on my page. All anchors are going to another page (/services/). I need that when users click any anchor on Home and go to Service page to change background of corresponded DIV for 5 seconds (make some highlight effect).

I've tried this code to make effect with 1 anchor, but it is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Check if the background color should be changed
  var shouldChangeBackground = true; // sessionStorage.getItem('changeBackground');
  
  if (shouldChangeBackground) {
    var $anchor = $('#anchor3');
    
    // Change the background color of Anchor 3
    $anchor.css('background-color', 'yellow');
    
    // Reset the flag after a few seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
      sessionStorage.removeItem('changeBackground');
    }, 3000); // Change '3000' to the desired delay in milliseconds (e.g., 5000 for 5 seconds)
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="anchor3">Anchor 3</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works to set the background, but you have no code to remove the background. Removing the storage value doesn't run any code. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Maybe you need to verify that the storage item is set as expected (or show us how you're doing that).

Answer (score 0):

## Web Storage Between Pages

### Updated with fade out effect

`sessionStorage` and `localStorage` are shared among all pages within the same domain. JavaScript between webpages is simple -- defined functions are shared and then calling the functions from the actual pages.

### `<script>`

- On both pages, load an external script that has the definitions of the functions (which will from now on will be referred to as *"event handlers"*).

  ```
  <script src="/lib/script.js"></script>
  ```
- On the home page, add a `<script>` element after the external script. Reference all of the `<a>` and register them to the "click" eve4nt in order to call an event handler defined in the previously mentioned external script. The event handler should save data to `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`.
- On the second page, add a `<script>` element after the external script as well. Get the data saved and apply it to the specified element (see **Example**).
- Place all `<script>` elements directly before the closing `</body>` tag.

  ```
    <script src="https://site.tld/path/to/script.js"></script>
    <script>
       // JavaScript specific to page
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

### `<a>`

Each link on the home page should have specific values for `[href]` and `[data-hex]`<sup>✱</sup> attributes.

- Assign the value of `[href]` on each link to a specific `#id` of an element located on the second page. The pattern should be: `"url#id"`.

  ```
  <a href="second_page.html#idOfElement"...>Link to Element</a>
  ```
- Assign the value of `[dara-hex]` on each link to a specific CSS color<sup>✤</sup>.

  ```
   <a href="lib/services.html#VPN" data-hex="#569CD6">VPN</a>
  ```

  <sup>✱ the actual name of the data-* attribute can be anything (see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19533402/2813224) about naming conventions)</sup>

  <sup>✤ the value can be any type that is accepted by CSS (see [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units))</sup>

## Example

The following example does not function since SO prohibits the use of the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). Go to this [Plunker](https://run.plnkr.co/preview/clhmq5sg7000e356oy50tp6xb/) to review a functioning example.

### `index.html`

### ```js
/**
 * This is the source of script.js which is shared by 
 * both pages.
 */

/**
 * A "click" event handler that when triggered will
 * store two values derived from a clicked link's
 * [data-hex] and [href] attributes in sessionStorage.
 * @param {Object<event>} - Default Event Object.
 */
function linkServices(event) {
  let hex, dom;
  // Reference the element user clicked
  const clk = event.target;
  // If the user clicked an <a>...
  if (clk.matches("a")) {
    // ...get <a>'s [data-hex] and...
    // ex. "#569CD6"
    hex = clk.dataset.hex;
    // ...[href] as an array...
    // ex. ["services.html", "VPN"]
    dom = clk.href.split("#");
    // ...store values in sessionStorage...
    // ex. "color": "#569CD6"
    sessionStorage.setItem("color", hex);
    // ex. "id": "VPN"
    sessionStorage.setItem("id", dom[1]);
  }
}

/**
 * An "load" event handler that when triggered will
 * get the 2 values stored in sessionStorage by the
 * event handler linkServices(). The value under key
 * "id" is used to find the specified <section> by #id, 
 * then once found, it's assigned a background-color 
 * determined by the value under the "color" key.
 * @param {Object<event>} - Default Event Object.
 */
function setSection(event) {
  // Get the 2 stored values saved by linkServices()
  // ex. "id": "VPN"
  let id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
  // ex. "color": #569CD6"
  let color = sessionStorage.getItem("color");
  // Get the `<section>` by it's #id
  // ex. <section id="VPN">...</section>
  const section = document.getElementById(id);
  // Assign "color" to section
  // ex. <section style="background-color: #569CD6"> ... </section>
  setTimeout(section.style.backgroundColor = color;
  // After a 5 second delay, change backround-color to "transparent"
  setTimeout(() => section.style.backgroundColor = "transparent", 5000);

}
```

```css
/**
 * This is the source of style.css which is shared by
 * both pages.
 */

:root {
  font: 5vmin/1.25 'Segoe UI';
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

header {
  margin: 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

section,
footer {
  width: 96vw;
  min-height: 50vh;
  transition: background-color 1s /* Animate with a "fading" effect */ 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <link href="lib/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <menu>
      <!--
          Suffix the url of [href] with target element's #id.
          ex. href="services.html#DSL"
          Assign any type of css color value to [data-hex].
          ex. data-hex="#F1C237"
        -->
      <li><a href="services.html#ISP" data-hex="#3FF23F">ISP</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html#VPN" data-hex="#569CD6">VPN</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html#DSL" data-hex="#F1C237">DSL</a></li>
    </menu>
  </nav>
  <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  <script>
    /**
     * Collect all <a> into a HTMLCollection then convert it 
     * into an array. Then register each <a> to the "click" 
     * event. When "click" event is fired, linkService() is called.
     */
    const lnx = Array.from(document.links);
    lnx.forEach(a => a.onclick = linkServices);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### `services.html`

### ```js
/**
 * This is the source of script.js which is shared by 
 * both pages.
 */

/**
 * A "click" event handler that when triggered will
 * store two values derived from a clicked link's
 * [data-hex] and [href] attributes in sessionStorage.
 * @param {Object<event>} - Default Event Object.
 */
function linkServices(event) {
  let hex, dom;
  // Reference the element user clicked
  const clk = event.target;
  // If the user clicked an <a>...
  if (clk.matches("a")) {
    // ...get <a>'s [data-hex] and...
    // ex. "#569CD6"
    hex = clk.dataset.hex;
    // ...[href] as an array...
    // ex. ["services.html", "VPN"]
    dom = clk.href.split("#");
    // ...store values in sessionStorage...
    // ex. "color": "#569CD6"
    sessionStorage.setItem("color", hex);
    // ex. "id": "VPN"
    sessionStorage.setItem("id", dom[1]);
  }
}

/**
 * An "load" event handler that when triggered will
 * get the 2 values stored in sessionStorage by the
 * event handler linkServices(). The value under key
 * "id" is used to find the specified <section> by #id, 
 * then once found, it's assigned a background-color 
 * determined by the value under the "color" key.
 * @param {Object<event>} - Default Event Object.
 */
function setSection(event) {
  // Get the 2 stored values saved by linkServices()
  // ex. "id": "VPN"
  let id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
  // ex. "color": #569CD6"
  let color = sessionStorage.getItem("color");
  // Get the `<section>` by it's #id
  // ex. <section id="VPN">...</section>
  const section = document.getElementById(id);
  // Assign "color" to section
  // ex. <section style="background-color: #569CD6"> ... </section>
  section.style.backgroundColor = color;
  // After a 5 second delay, change backround-color to "transparent"
  setTimeout(() => section.style.backgroundColor = "transparent", 5000);
}
```

```css
/**
 * This is the source of style.css which is shared by
 * both pages.
 */

:root {
  font: 5vmin/1.25 'Segoe UI';
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

header {
  margin: 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

section,
footer {
  width: 96vw;
  min-height: 50vh;
  transition: background-color 1s /* Animate with a "fading" effect */;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <link href="lib/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav><a href="index.html">Home</a></nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="ISP">
      <h2>Internet Service Provider</h2>
      <p>A company that provides subscribers with access to the internet.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="VPN">
      <h2>Virtual Private Network</h2>
      <p>An arrangement whereby a secure, apparently private network is achieved using encryption over a public network, typically the internet.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="DSL">
      <h2>Digital Subscriber Line</h2>
      <p>A technology for high-speed network or Internet access over voice lines.</p>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
  </main>

  <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  <script>
    /**
     * Call setSection().
     */
    setSection();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```